# Multiple instances of a class with shared modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'm having some problems with running multiple instances of a class, while at the same time using ES6 modules for a cleaner project structure.

I will try to explain my problem below. My real project is much larger and more complex, but I'm using this as an example.

## Version 1

**main.js**

```
import App from './app';

let instance1 = new App,
    instance2 = new App;
```

**app.js**

```
import Layer from './layer'
import Element from './element'

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.layer = new Layer;
    this.element = new Element;
  }
  addLayer() {
    this.layer.addLayer();  
  }
  addElement() {
    this.element.addElement();
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

**layer.js**

```
class Layer {
  constructor() {
    this.layers = [];
  }
  addLayer(name) {
    this.layers.push({
        name: name
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Layer;
```

**element.js**

```
class Element {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = [];
  }
  addElement(name) {
    this.elements.push({
      name: name
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Element;
```

Now I get a unique instance for `instance1` and `instance2`, containing it's own layers and elements. The problem comes when **element.js** and **layer.js** want to talk to each other. I can't `import Layer from './layer'` *inside* **element.js** without having to create a new instance, not being able to access the layers created from other locations within the app.

## Version 2

**main.js**

```
import App from './app';

let instance1 = new App,
    instance2 = new App;
```

**app.js**

```
import layer from './layer'
import element from './element'

class App {
  addLayer() {
    layer.addLayer();  
  }
  addElement() {
    element.addElement();
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

**layer.js**

```
class Layer {
  constructor() {
    this.layers = [];
  }
  addLayer(name) {
    this.layers.push({
      name: name
    });
  }
}

let layer = new Layer;
module.exports = layer;
```

**element.js**

```
class Element {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = [];
  }
  addElement(name) {
    this.elements.push({
      name: name
    });
  }
}

let element = new Element;
module.exports = element;
```

In this case I can access the layers from **elements.js** and the other way around, but they will also be shared across both instances of the app which is not what I want.

This started out as a single **app.js** which contained everything and worked fine, but as the project grew, it became really very hard to maintain. But the below is an example of what I want to achieve.

**app.js**

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.layers = [];
    this.elements = [];
  }
  addLayer(name) {
    this.layers.push({
      name: name
    });
  }
  addElement(name) {
    this.elements.push({
      name: name
    });
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

Is there a way to get the best from both worlds here? I have thought about something like a *store* for each instance of the app, keeping track of it's own layers and elements but sharing it's functionality, but I'm not sure where to put it and how to pass a reference to it around the app.

### Edit

To clarify because I got the question in the comments. In reality this is a much larger project with lots of different modules that interact with each other in a lot of different ways. The minimal version above is just for the purpose of this question, but here are some additional parts as an example of interaction between **layer.js** and **element.js**.

**main.js**

```
instance1.element.get('element1').addToLayer('background');
```

**layer.js**

```
.addLayer(name) {
    this.layers.push({
        name: name,
        elements: [],
        add: (element) => {
            this.elements.push(element);
        }
    });
}
```

**element.js**

```
import layer from './layer';

...

.get(name) {
    let el;
    for(item in this.elements) {
        if(item.name == name) {
            el = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return el;
}
.addElement(name) {
    this.elements.push({
        name: name,
        addToLayer: (name) => {
            let l;
            for(item in layer.layers) {
               if(item.name == name {
                   l = item;
                   break;
               }
            }
            if(l) l.add(this);
        }
    });
}
```

In **Version 1**, `layer.layers` would be empty here because I would have to create a new instance of it. In **Version 2**, it would work fine but all instances of App would share the same `layer.layers`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would layers and elements need to talk to each other? What do they have to do with each other, can you give an example of them interacting?

Comment: Sure! A layer can contain elements, so the element might have a method called `.addToLayer(name)` which should add the element to the layer. A layer may look like `{ name: 'layer1', elements: [] }`, and I want to be able to access the array of layers, find the right layer and add the element to it. But also as I said, this is a very minimal example of a much larger application. In reality there are about 20 different modules that has a lot of interaction between each other. I wanted to simplify everything as much as possible for the purpose of this question.

Comment: I think you'll need to pass the `layer` object (or the whole `App` instance) as a parameter to `addToLayer`, otherwise it doesn't know where to resolve the name. If you don't want to pass it explicitly, you will need to pass the reference while you are constructing the layer, and store for each layer the app to which it belongs. In neither of these solutions you will need to import one module into the other, btw.

Comment: @Bergi I have been experimenting with instance handling within the modules, like keeping an id for each instance and passing it around or having a store module that contains all the arrays and just letting the `add()`, `get()` and so on remain in the other shared modules. There are of course ways to make it work, but what I don't like is that it becomes very complex again and almost defeats the purpose of what I was trying to do. I had the feeling that I could not have been the only one running into this, but maybe I have to rethink the entire structure from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

### Version 1

#### app.js

```
import Layer from './layer'
import Element from './element'

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.layer = new Layer(this);
    this.element = new Element(this);
  }
  addLayer() {
    this.layer.addLayer();  
  }
  addElement() {
    this.element.addElement();
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

#### layer.js

```
class Layer {
  constructor(app) {
    this.App = app;
    this.layers = [];
  }
  addLayer(name) {
    this.layers.push({
        name: name
    });
    this.App.element.addElement(name); // Element method
  }
  foo() {
    console.log('Hey you!!');
  }
}

module.exports = Layer;
```

#### element.js

```
class Element {
  constructor(app) {
    this.App = app;
    this.elements = [];
  }
  addElement(name) {
    // ...
    this.App.layer.foo(); // I can talk with Layer class
  }
}

module.exports = Element;
```

See also https://github.com/jonataswalker/es6-sample-project

Comment: You should omit the `return this` from the constructors

Comment: @Bergi but then how can I communicate between them ("the children")?

Comment: That has nothing to do with communication. A constructor called with `new` *always* returns the new instance, there's no need to overwrite that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been tackling the same problem over the last couple of days and came up with a method which does not require the use of classes.

My complete solution is for a map control which needs to be instantiated for dashboards with multiple maps.

Disclaimer; I did not come up with this solution by myself but used the advise of a [code mentor](https://www.codementor.io/clanehin).

---

**main.mjs**

```
import App from './app.mjs';

const instance1 = App();

const instance2 = App();
```

---

**app.mjs**

```
import Layer from './layer.mjs';

import Element from './element.mjs';

export default () => {

  const app = {};

  Layer(app);

  Element(app);

  return app;

}
```

---

**layer.mjs / element.mjs**

```
export default app => {

  app.layers = [];

  app.addLayer = name => {
    app.layer.push({
      name: name
    })
  }

}
```

---

Additionally I create a lib.mjs file which I bundle with Webpack and use as a source library file. In here import the instance constructor 'App' and assign this function to the window object.

[Here is a jsfiddle in which I import the bundled library and create two map instances.](https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/qLdhmz3a/3/)

**lib.mjs**

```
import App from './app.mjs';

window.App = App;
```